# How many seconds can wit.ai take the input in speech to text ?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, wit.ai

I'm doing the Speech to Text in python. I have mentioned the no.of seconds to take as 500 as I want a continuous speech recognition, but the voice recording is taking only for 5 seconds. So I'm doubting whether it is with the wit api or with my code.

```
def RecSpeech(AUDIO, no.of_seconds = 500):

         record_audio(no.of_seconds, AUDIO)

         audio = read_audio(AUDIO)
```

Comment: if you increase `no.of_seconds` does it still only last 5 seconds?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint  yes even though i increase it to 500, it still lasts for 5 seconds only.

Comment: so any number specified between 5 and 500?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint I have given the range as 500 .. do u have any idea regarding this ?